# Selecting Non-existent Data With MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

I'm trying to select data between two date range. However not all data are being inserted daily. Below is sample of the table:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM attendance;
+------------+-------+
| date       | total |
+------------+-------+
| 2012-07-02 |   100 |
| 2012-07-04 |    70 |
| 2012-07-05 |    78 |
+------------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The scenario is I want to get total of attendance from 2012-07-02 till 2012-07-04. Based on the data above I will get

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE date BETWEEN '2012-07-02' AND '2012-07-04';
+------------+-------+
| date       | total |
+------------+-------+
| 2012-07-02 |   100 |
| 2012-07-04 |    70 |
+------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

However my objective is to have 2012-07-03 included in the result.

```
+------------+-------+
| date       | total |
+------------+-------+
| 2012-07-02 |   100 |
| 2012-07-03 |     0 |
| 2012-07-04 |    70 |
+------------+-------+
```

Is this possible to be done through MySQL? I did look into [temporary table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html). But still unable to achieve the objective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem with a simple solution.

Create a regular table, say REF_DATE, and store in it all dates for like 3 years or whatever time span you would need.

Then use this table on the left of a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT REF.date,IFNULL(A.total,0) as total FROM REF_DATE REF 
LEFT OUTER JOIN attendance 
ON REF.date=A.date
A WHERE REF.date BETWEEN '2012-07-02' AND '2012-07-04';
```

DATE is a keyword in MySQL, I have used it here for readability. Use a different column name.

Comment: Thanks. The provided SQL didn't actually work. A minor fix got the job done.

`SELECT REF.date, IFNULL(A.total, 0) as total FROM REF_DATE REF 
LEFT OUTER JOIN attendance A 
ON REF.date = A.date 
WHERE REF.date BETWEEN '20-07-02' AND '2012-07-04';`

Comment: To whoever has downvoted this - Have the decency to comment why you downvoted it.

Answer (score 1):

You can enumerate dates as derived pseudo-table (with `UNION`) and then join it with your data

```
SELECT dates.date, COALESCE(attendance.total,0) AS total FROM (
SELECT '2012-07-02' AS date
UNION ALL SELECT '2012-07-03'
UNION ALL SELECT '2012-07-04'
) AS dates
LEFT JOIN attendance USING(date)
```

Edit: added `COALESCE` to return `0` instead of `NULL` on missing records.

Comment: This solution and one provided by Priyank works well. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

MySQL cannot generate data that isn't there. If you want non-existent dates, you'll need to have a temporary table that contains the full date range you join against. Another alternative is to maintain a server-side variable and do some date math for each row, which is ugly

```
select @dateval := '2012-07-02';
SELECT @dateval := @dateval + INTERVAL 1 DAY from ...
```