# Generate Dates starting from a date returned by a condition - SQL

Tags: sql, date

A [`series of dates` with a specified `interval` can be generated using a `variable` and a `static date` as per the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13777730/table-date-column-comparison-with-a-generated-dates-list-mysql) that I asked earlier. However when there's a `where` clause to produce a start date, the `dates generation` seems to stop and only shows the first interval date. I also checked other posts, those that I found **[e.g. 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141507/how-to-generate-a-range-of-dates-in-sql-server), [e.g. 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337905/selecting-non-existent-data-with-mysql/11338539#11338539), [e.g. 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271595/getting-dates-between-a-range-of-dates?rq=1)** are shown with a `static date` or using CTE.. I am looking for a solution **without** `storedprocedures/functions`...

**This works:**

```
SELECT DATE(DATE_ADD('2012-01-12', 
INTERVAL @i:=@i+30 DAY) ) AS dateO
FROM members, (SELECT @i:=0) r
where @i < DATEDIFF(now(), date '2012-01-12') 
;
```

**These don't:**

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(date '2012-01-12', 
INTERVAL @j:=@j+30 DAY) AS dateO, @j
FROM `members`, (SELECT @j:=0) s
where @j <= DATEDIFF(now(), date '2012-01-12') 
and mmid = 100
;

SELECT DATE_ADD(stdate, 
INTERVAL @k:=@k+30 DAY) AS dateO, @k
FROM `members`, (SELECT @k:=0) t
where @k <= DATEDIFF(now(), stdate)
and mmid = 100
;
```

- [SQLFIDDLE REFERENCE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15dcb/24)

**Expected Results:**

Be the same as the first query results given it starts generating dates with `stDate` of `mmid=100`.

Preferably in `ANSI SQL` so it can be supported in `MYSQL, SQL Server/MS Access SQL` as [`Oracle` has `trunc` and `rownum` given per this query with 14 votes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418318/generate-a-range-of-dates-using-sql) and `PostGres` has `generatge_Series` function. **I would like to know if this is a *bug* or a *limitation* in `MYSQL`?**

---

PS: I have asked a similar quetion before. It was based on `static date values` where as this one is based on a date value from a table column based on a condition.

Comment: If you use `and mmid = 100` in the WHERE clause, you're going to get a single row that's derived from the row in which mmid = 100. What are you *really* trying to do? Show the date from every 30-day interval between two dates?

Comment: I want to generate 10 day interval for each member taking their start date till now. 30 day was just an example as 10 day. You can see in my table there is a date for each member. So for 10 members I need 10 different and separate date sets give in my case each start date is unique. Please let me know if you require further clarification. I even tried assigning start date using a variable that was set via select into query. It just doesn't work.

Comment: @JW. Your SQL skills are admirable. Can you share some tips on getting so fast with SQLFiddle as well as shooting the qeries(including very easy to advanced ones) quickly? Did you just pick it up over few months or how did it go to get to this speed :) ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to insure cross-platform compatibility is to use a calendar table. In its simplest form

```
create table calendar (
  cal_date date primary key
);

insert into calendar values
('2013-01-01'),
('2013-01-02'); -- etc.
```

There are many ways to generate dates for insertion.

Instead of using a WHERE clause to *generate* rows, you use a WHERE clause to select rows. To select October of this year, just

```
select cal_date
from calendar
where cal_date between '2013-10-01' and '2013-10-31';
```

It's reasonably compact--365,000 rows to cover a period of 1000 years. That ought to cover most business scenarios.

If you need cross-platform date arithmetic, you can add a tally column.

```
drop table calendar;
create table calendar (
  cal_date date primary key,
  tally integer not null unique check (tally > 0)
);

insert into calendar values ('2012-01-01', 1); -- etc.
```

To select all the dates of 30-day intervals, starting on 2012-01-12 and ending at the end of the calendar year, use

```
select cal_date
from calendar
where ((tally - (select tally
                 from calendar
                 where cal_date = '2012-01-12')) % 30 ) = 0;

cal_date
--
2012-01-12
2012-02-11
2012-03-12
2012-04-11
2012-05-11
2012-06-10
2012-07-10
2012-08-09
2012-09-08
2012-10-08
2012-11-07
2012-12-07
```

If your "mmid" column is guaranteed to have no gaps--an unspoken requirement for a calendar table--you can use the "mmid" column in place of my "tally" column.

Comment: Thanks @Catcall. I will update my question to say, no calendar table :-)  Even there's a calendar table it just doesn't suit the question, as your example still retrieving dates with `static range`. I am curious to know why the query fails to I generate dates given a date based on a condition, which is a valid scenario.